# need help converting buffer to string in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I created node udp listener and the incoming data is a buffer, so I tried the following

`console.log(message.toString);`

and this is what I get in my console

> �>�?F��GD�HDӑ
>                �-�b�����8��J;prj�t�*8�������9�U��,mi=:�=��>�?��>�;�>2�<�S����7��(�
>   PHD�Dl:�DT�J;��z)\��8�B{8�B`w�B`w�B�?(�B�=Ekv=E��                                   �>
>   �>�?F��GD�HDӑ
>                �-�b����ـ8g�J;�Yj��Z8����@#�9�U��,mi=:�=��>�?���>88�>o�=��"��¬��$�(�~�Xa�7���T��7�&*�,��SPHD�Dl:�D�J;��z)\��8�B{8�B`w�B`w�B�?(�B=E�v=E��
>   .�>�?F��GD�HDӑ

Here is all my code

```
var PORT = 33333;
var HOST = '';

var dgram = require('dgram');
var server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

server.on('listening', function () {
    var address = server.address();
    console.log('UDP Server listening on ' + address.address + ':' + address.port);
});

server.on('message', function (message, remote) {
   console.log(message.toString());
    // console.log(remote);
});

server.bind(PORT, HOST);
```

Comment: What kind of data does the buffer contain? What did you expect to see in the console?

Comment: Where comes that data from ? I assume your source send no valid data than can be converted back to strings

Comment: so the data comes from forza 7 and I think you might be right. Found a link to code where this is done and I was going about it all wrong https://github.com/gsbarreto/simple-udp-server-fm7/blob/master/server.js